# Field permission for Administrator

Tags: 8

How to disable this fields for Administator?

[image: Administrator is selected per default.]

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers. Please don't post questions with pictures containing most of the context. Try describing with some sentences what you want to do and why. Then you can add pictures to illustrate the context. This makes it easier for the search function to index your question for others. - As for your question: You can't. The site administrators always have ALL permissions. Consider creating a separate, less privileged admin role.

Comment: If you wish to disable a certain permissions for the administrator, the short answer is that you cannot. Admin always has all permissions enabled. You will need to create a new role.

Comment: You can't with permissions, but you can do that with your own hook_entity_field_access() implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should be administrator.

```
if (in_array('administrator', $account->getRoles())) {
  return AccessResult::forbidden();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! While the code can be correct, the answer doesn't say where to add the code.

Answer (score 0):

Install [Disable Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/disable_field) module and install. After installation go-to `admin/structure/types/manage/YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE/fields` and edit the desired field. In the bottom, you can see `DISABLE FIELD SETTINGS` open that and you can choose to disable option in `DISABLE THIS FIELD ON ADD CONTENT FORM?` and `DISABLE THIS FIELD ON EDIT CONTENT FORM?`. In that Select `Disable for certain roles` and choose administrator. After that save and that field will be disabled in ADD/EDIT based on your selection

Comment: It does not work for mandatory fields.